# Passing parameters to VB script using bat file

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I need to pass the paramter to the excel macro from the batch file.
Please suggest a way to achieve this.

Comment: Show your code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of calling a vbscript from a batch file and passing it parameters from the batch file from user supplied input.

```
@echo off
setlocal

set /p "param1=Enter Start Date: "
set /p "param2=Enter End Date: "

cscript //nologo yourscript.vbs param1 param2
```

Comment: Hi,I need to pass these parameters to the excel file from the command prompt/batch file.

Comment: Are you instantiating the excel object through vbscript?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% if I understand, but if running Windows 7/8 (or maybe even XP), you could call your vbscript like this:

cscript script.vbs /curdate:"30" /enddate:"-30"

Inside your vbscript, you could simply add something like this:

[Script.vbs] --

```
curdate = wscript.arguments.Named.Item("curdate")
enddate = wscript.arguments.Named.Item("enddate")

wscript.echo curdate
wscript.echo enddate
```

--

I don't think this is exactly what you are asking. Perhaps you could rephrase your question to make it more clear?